# Can i put text in the left and in the right side of the elements of a listview?

Tags: android, listview

i have to make a listview that haves a list of names, and also, aligned to the left, but in the same field, the sex of the person, male or female

is possible to do it? how?

code examples welcome

EDIT

I try with the first user answer, and i got this exception: `12-14 22:39:56.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(917): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`

this is the code of the XML item i make:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Left side" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Right side" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the code where i have my list:

```
public class PendingInvitations extends ListActivity {

......
.....
....    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    private List<String> usernames=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<friends.size();i++)
              {
                usernames.add(i,friends.get(i).getFullName());
              }


              setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item2, usernames));
```

Comment: i can make the list, but i dont know how to put another text on the same element but aligned to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be the view that is used for each cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Left side" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Right side" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

this is an example since i have no idea where your knowledge is at with lists, if the above xml was called "temp.xml" you would use this in the setlistadapter function

```
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    public class FooList extends ListActivity extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] listItems = {"item 1", "item 2 ", "list", "android", "item 3", "foobar", "bar", }; 
        @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_listview);

             // implement your own adapter

         }

    }
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
                // to findViewById() on each row.
                ViewHolder holder;

                // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
                // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
                // by ListView is null.
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.temp, null);

                    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                    // we want to bind data to.
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.left = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.left);
                    holder.right = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.right);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                    // and the ImageView.
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

                holder.left.setText("left text");
                holder.right.setText("right text");

                return convertView;
            }

    class ViewHolder
    {
         public TextView left;
        public TextView right;
    }
```

Comment: also it crash... i am editing first post with the crash and the code i try

Comment: you need to implement your own list adapter and  implement the "getView" function , look at this example http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html  and pay close attention to the getView function, in the example where it says 

"convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);"

this is where you want to use the temp.xml layout

Comment: i edited my code to get you started, you'll still have to implement a few more functions to get it to compile probably but with the link above as an example that should get you started in the right direction, i thought you had a little more understanding of lists so i changed my original post, hope its more clear

Answer (score 0):

Each item of a ListView has to be a View. This includes ViewGroups. So you can use any Layout to arrange several Views inside a ListView item.

Comment: Have a look at Slim's answer.